# What's wrong with this JavaScript? Getting "ReferenceError: newArray not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.get('/v1/zillow/houses?', function(req, res) {
  var city;
  var array = [];
  var newArray = [];
  if (req.query.city) {
    city = req.query.city;
    array = data;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i].city == city) {
        newArray.push(array[i]);
      }
    }
    res.status(200).send(newArray);
  } else {
    res.status(404).send(array);
  }
});
```

Not sure why I am getting this error. `newArray` is clearly defined as empty array.

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from this code?

Comment: Any reason you don't use `let newArray = data.filter(d => d.city == city)`?

Comment: The error message should have a line number. Which line is getting the error?

Comment: it seems that newArray is defined within the if statement if (req.query.city), which means that if req.query.city is false, newArray will not be defined.

Comment: The problem i can see is that the variable 'data' is not defined. So  array = data; would cause an error